# Angular app gives error when refreshing from any route but blank

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am not able to access the route directly using example.com/movie . I get an error on the page saying **Cannot GET /movie** .

When I refresh the page from a specific route I get the same error **Cannot GET /xyz-route**

My app.routing.module is

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'movie',
component: movieComponent },
  {path: 'home',
component: homeComponent },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/movie', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

How can i fix this issue ?

Comment: can you share StackBlitz example?

Comment: Won't make sense. The problem only occurs when the app is deployed. In localhost: the issue is not present. So when the app is deployed to Azure,GCP,AWS and a domain name is attached the issue comes about. It may be because I did not place pathMatch on all the routes.

Comment: Is your angular app not hosted through asp.net core? The `UseSpa()` and `AddSpaStaticFiles()` should take care of everything

Answer (score 0):

In your route configuration, use the component classes instead of string literals:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'movie', component: MovieComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/movie', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Comment: Sorry. I did that. I made a mistake while typing on here.

Comment: I have figure out half of the issue. I need to use **useHash**. After using that option, the page refreshes were working fine. I still cant access the page directly by saying **example.com/movie** .

Comment: That's because your webserver (apache, nginx, iis, ...) is litterally looking for that file instead of loading the index.html. [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/web.config) a web.config that rewrites the request-url for all requests to `/index.html` (iis only)